# How to Loop Materialize Grid on Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, grid, materialize

I'm trying to loop some images type "Instagram Grid" using the materializeCss Grid that it provides.

So my code is like this:

```
<div class="section">
  <% @places.each do |place| %>
    <div class="places-grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s4 l4 m4 places-holder">
        <div class="card hoverable">
          <div class="card-image materialboxed" width="50">
            <%= image_tag place.picture.url if place.picture %>
            <span class="picture responsive-img"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content mar-bottom">
            <%= render place %>
            <% if current_user?(place.user)%>
              <%= link_to place, method: :delete, class:"btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light red", data: { confirm: "Seguro que quieres eliminar?" } do %>
                <i class="material-icons">delete</i> 
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

But what this code does, it makes my images in a column like this:

```
Card- with image
Card- with image
Card- with image
```

And I want it like this:

```
  Card- with image        Card- with image         Card- with image
```

As I know the css code for the grid is correct but maybe the way im trying to loop it is wrong. I will appreciate so much your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the `.each` block as below as your current code loop creates 3 rows using the class `row` :

```
  <div class="section">
      <div class="places-grid">
        <div class="row">
          <% @places.each do |place| %>
          <div class="col s4 l4 m4 places-holder">
            <div class="card hoverable">
              <div class="card-image materialboxed" width="50">
                <%= image_tag place.picture.url if place.picture %>
                <span class="picture responsive-img"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="card-content mar-bottom">
                <%= render place %>
                <% if current_user?(place.user)%>
                  <%= link_to place, method: :delete, class:"btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light red", data: { confirm: "Seguro que quieres eliminar?" } do %>
                    <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                  <% end %>
                <% end %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```